# Sitecore Identity Server SSL error - Thumbprint Error

Tags: identity-server

I am installing Sitecore 10.2 in our environment. My network team setup the DNS and SSL all in the **F5 server** NOT in the physical server where i am installing the Sitecore Identity Server and CMS websites.

In the Identity server website, i am noticing that i need to update the "thumbprint and certificate location and certificate store name" in the configuration file "**\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml**"

Below is the config elements where i need to provide the thumbprint and certificate name and location

```
  <CertificateThumbprint></CertificateThumbprint>
  <CertificateStoreLocation></CertificateStoreLocation>
  <CertificateStoreName></CertificateStoreName>
```

I can get the thumbprint from my network team and provide in the config file.

**My Question:**

1. Since the SSL/DNS are configured in F5 server, this SSL certificate is not available in the physical server where i have installed the identity server, what should i give the certificate store location? and certificate store name?
2. Also, in the same config file, there was an element "ClientSecret1" what's the purpose of that and how it is connected between Identity Server and CMS?

When i just provide the thumbprint and not provide the location and store, identity server website is throwing error in the browser "Page Can not be found". Also getting error in log file that

Comment: Im also facing same error in my identity server

Answer (score 1):

### Certificate:

I believe in order for Identity Server to securely operate you must have the certificate installed on the same server. If on the slim chance there is a way to make Identity Server operate without the certificate locally, it's not likely something implemented by Sitecore. For this issue you should submit a support ticket to confirm that it's supported or not. Then update your question with details you discovered from Sitecore/forums.

### Client Secret:

The secret is configured in both the Identity Server configuration and the Sitecore CM connection strings. These must match. There are multiple scenarios you need the Client Secret (such as working with the CLI).

Documentation can be found [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-a-sitecore-instance-and-sitecore-identity-server.html).